# Print specified output in subrocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, output

I want to print specified output in subrocess 
Here is my code:

```
from subprocess import check_output

output = check_output(['python3', 'code.py']).decode('ascii')
print(output)
```

The output is:

```
Tom
John
```

How can I print just `Tom` or just `John` instead of both of them?
I have tried `print(output[0])` to print `Tom` but I get only `T`.

Comment: `print(output.splitlines()[0])`

Comment: Thanlks @OlvinRoght

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look on steps you've already done:

1. You call [`check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) and it returns output in the form of [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes);
2. Then You call [`bytes.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode), which returns [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str).

As a result you get multi-line string. You've tried to access to first line using index `0`, but you got first char instead of first line. It happened, cause accessing to string by index will return you char from this index.

To get first line you should split lines of your multi-line string (convert str to list of str). There's built-in function [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) which does what you need.

---

So, to upgrade your code we need to add one more line before your `print()` statement:

```
output_lines = output.splitlines()
```

After that you can access to line by index:

```
print(output_lines[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

You have single string and you can use any string's function.

You can split it and create list with lines

```
lines = output.split('\n')
```

And then display only first line

```
print(lines[0])
```

Comment: why not [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines)?

Comment: @OlvinRoght it is doesn't matter. I like this one.

Comment: I have to mention that there's special function which split lines even if you ignore it.

Comment: @OlvinRoght you can even create answer with own version